# suEXEC before Apache dead

Tags: apache-2.2, suexec

One of our Apache server went down. After the web server restarts, there is a red light on the server panel and we are contacting hardware vendor to investigate any potential hardware issue.

The last line in `error_log` before server down is:

```
[notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suExec is used to change the user under which a CGI script runs. The above notice simply tells you it is enabled. It is commonly seen as part of Apache starting for instance, when I restart apache, I get:

```
[Thu Jul 07 22:09:41 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Jul 07 22:09:43 2011] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Jul 07 22:09:43 2011] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled
[Thu Jul 07 22:09:44 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Jul 07 22:09:44 2011] [notice] Digest: done
[Thu Jul 07 22:09:44 2011] [notice] FastCGI: wrapper mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Jul 07 22:09:44 2011] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid xxxx)
[Thu Jul 07 22:09:44 2011] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled
[Thu Jul 07 22:09:44 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Unix) mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 DAV/2 PHP/5.3.6 mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/1.0.0a-fips SVN/1.6.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
```